# How to dynamically infer type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I make the compiler understand that the return type of the `parse` method is linked to the input of the `serialize` method and it is dynamic?

```
type QUESTION = {
  parse: (value: string) => any
  serialize: (value: ReturnType<QUESTION['parse']>) => string
}

const idsQuestions: QUESTION[] = [
  {
    parse: (input) => input.split('\n'),
    serialize: (ids) => ids.join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as string[]
  },
  {
    parse: (input) => input.split('\n').reduce((acc, id) => ({
      ...acc,
      [id]: true,
    }), {}),
    serialize: (ids) => Object.keys(ids).join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as { [string] => boolean }
  }
]

// expect this to throw an error on build
const questionWithError: QUESTION = {
  parse: () => false, // return type is boolean
  serialize: (ids) => ids.join('\n') // but ids is not interpreted as boolean, so compiler doens't give an error
}
```

I've tried some uses of generics and `unknown`, but could not make it work.
Tried to use `infer` also, but could not understand exactly how to work with it

I could have something hardcoded like this, but I wanted it to be dynamic

```
type QUESTION<T> = {
  parse: (value: string) => T
  serialize: (value: T) => string
}

const idsQuestions: [
  QUESTION<string[]>,
  QUESTION<{ [k: string]: boolean }>,
] = [
  {
    parse: (input) => input.split('\n'),
    serialize: (ids) => ids.join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as string[]
  },
  {
    parse: (input) => input.split('\n').reduce((acc, id) => ({
      ...acc,
      [id]: true,
    }), {}),
    serialize: (ids) => Object.keys(ids).join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as { [string] => boolean }
  }
]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigqgUQMoBUCSB5AclAvFAbwFgAoKKMAQwCcBnCALigAoA3SgGwFdGpbhqASwB2AcwCUeAHxRKwkKXL0hnQQC9ebTjyYAlCMC7VhKcBAA88ZOmwBtAORU6EewF0pk3DP5CxpAL6kpADGAPbC-FCCACa0MDz8guG0TFaomFi2rnhQtoqE+eRO9EzMImBcwJ4y5ZUAdLRgHILAzPYAOsL24gA0hXwQKs0apTG01VGxdQBWoSJtnd1QAPTLUBAAHpDBwJO0UMChUABG0CLAg2DUBhDRsvs+IqJZ+f59ZAUfRTQlLLVV0iiwgqwAaTRaCy64jq12iXGCEGYzEowWCPUmE2YxC+5CgdXxKLR-XIthiriYAh471xUH8vUIdOpuOUglUIz+sQmGGO0wgOzqAGsICBaGVOTM5sJIUtVustnzdmMDkdTkCLtQrjc7pR9gRco8xNkvCdQqEOBA5LTXqRXEESLLNttdsAABaCfaHA4u6ihADusmE62oPuoUHCJy4gg40RCyV2AEcEsAksIAOotF0IYOhaipRDpbA5bHfZylCYAM049HRsuuhmMBzMUX2x1N5rk+RZbM0YwmYwl8w6UJWa2OlT2zagwlCiuE6s1F21LbbFuE6NoRzCAFswFHBlBoqEIBF7LtRIJWNBLYMQwEgA)

Comment: Couldn't you just make `QUESTION<T>` and then use `T` as parameter and `T[]` as return type for parse, and upside down for serialize?

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Edited my question to be closer to my use case

Comment: `expect ids to be interpreted as { [string] => boolean }` what do you mean it's not supposed to throw an error.

Comment: yeah this one is correct, but the `() => false` right below have an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is doable without some helper functions or making it excessively verbose. Make a function that could help determine what `T` should be.

```
type QUESTION<T> = {
  parse: (value: string) => T
  serialize: (value: T) => string
}

function QUESTION<T>(parse: (value: string) => T, serialize: (value: T) => string): QUESTION<T> {
  return { parse, serialize };
}

const idsQuestions = [
  QUESTION(
    (input) => input.split('\n'),
    (ids) => ids.join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as string[]
  ),
  QUESTION(
    (input) => input.split('\n').reduce((acc, id) => ({
      ...acc,
      [id]: true,
    }), {} as Record<string, boolean>),
    (ids) => Object.keys(ids).join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as { [string] => boolean }
  )
] as const;
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `genric-type`.

With this feature, you can tie between Types dynamically

```
interface Question<T>  {
  parse: (value: string) => T
  serialize: (value: T) => string
}

const idsQuestion: Question<string[]> = {
  parse: (input) => input.split('\n'),
  serialize: (ids) => ids.join('\n') // expect ids to be interpreted as string[]
}

// expect this to throw an error on build
const questionWithError: Question<boolean> = {
  parse: () => false, // return type is boolean
  serialize: (ids) => ids.join('\n') // the transpiler will show an error
}
```

Comment: The real use case is a bit more complex than the example, so using generics this way solves this problem, but don't solve the case I have.

Comment: so ask your complex one

Comment: question edited